# Как извлечь фразы из файла PHP?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть много файлов PHP, где есть фразы на русском. Мне нужно их извлечь. Надо именно извлечь фразы целиком, а не слова.

Пробовал использовать такую конструкцию

```
preg_match_all("|>([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я ]+)<\/|is", $html,$strings);
```

Но не выбирает.

Comment: Используйте парсер DOM сначала, чтобы извлечь *текст*. Потом уж и колдуйте над регулярным выражением. Сейчас непонятно, в чём проблема.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под "парсер дом"? я не могу делать выборку по тегам, так как я не знаю, между какими может быть текст

Comment: Зачем теги? Вам же нужны текстовые элементы.

Comment: не совсем понимаю. можете пример скинуть? или более подробно объяснить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *извлечь фразы целиком*

Составьте шаблон подобным образом:

```
$str = file_get_contents('file.php');

preg_match_all('~\p{Cyrillic}+(?:\h+\p{Cyrillic}+)*~u', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

---

`\p{Cyrillic} +` - одна или более русских букв

`(?: \h+ \p{Cyrillic} + ) *` - необязательная группа символов, состоящая из горизонтальных пробельных символов, после которых следует одна или более русских букв.

Comment: спасибо, работает